# Angular 8: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Any idea why I am getting this error in my Angular 8 application:

`ERROR in src/app/_services/resolver.service.ts(13,23): error TS2339: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.`

This is the way I have imported it:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResolverService implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {

  constructor() { }

  resolve() {
    return Observable.of('Hello Resolver!').delay(2000);
  }
}
```

According to all the other threats I have seen pertaining to this I am doing it correctly as I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Observable.of` was the older syntax. With "lettable" or "pipeable" operators, you import each individually and pipe them together. Not sure where `delay` is coming from but assuming you're importing it from `rxjs/operators`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResolverService implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {

  constructor() { }

  resolve() {
    return of('Hello Resolver!').pipe(delay(2000));
  }
}
```